# Is it possible to trigger an event when a user clicks a local notification

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, notifications

In Unity3d, is it possible to trigger an event when a user clicks a local notification in iOS?

I am letting the user know that it is their turn in a turn-based game, using a LocalNotification with NotificationServices. I want the user to be able to click on the notification, and have the game load the latest turn information. I'm not sure how to have something trigger when the user clicks on the notification though.

Answer (score 1):

When user click the notification didReceivelocalNotification method in the AppDelegate will be called. Put your code inside that method.